# Prefer a local mirror without changing /etc/apt/sources.list?

Tags: apt

We have local mirrors for Ubuntu (Debian) at http://ubuntu.wikimedia.org/ubuntu/ (https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/debian/).  I want to configure clients to prefer downloading/only download packages from these mirrors instead of http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ (http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/).  I can do this successfully by replacing the URLs in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, however I am interested in doing this *without* changing `/etc/apt/sources.list` so that the customization is obvious and can easily be reverted.

I have created `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wikimedia-mirror.list` with the content:

```
deb http://ubuntu.wikimedia.org/ubuntu/ trusty main universe
deb-src http://ubuntu.wikimedia.org/ubuntu/ trusty main universe
```

and `/etc/apt/preferences.d/wikimedia-mirror.pref` with:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin "ubuntu.wikimedia.org"
Pin-Priority: 501
```

After `apt-get update`, this will cause packages from the mirror to have priority 501, yet `apt-get` will download those packages from the original sources:

```
scfc@toolsbeta-t68121-trusty:~$ apt-cache policy zsh-doc
zsh-doc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.2-3ubuntu6
  Version table:
     5.0.5-4ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
     5.0.2-3ubuntu6 0
        500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        501 http://ubuntu.wikimedia.org/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
scfc@toolsbeta-t68121-trusty:~$ sudo apt-get install zsh-doc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  zsh-doc
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,274 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,856 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main zsh-doc all 5.0.2-3ubuntu6 [2,274 kB]
Fetched 2,274 kB in 3s (631 kB/s)    
Selecting previously unselected package zsh-doc.
(Reading database ... 38984 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../zsh-doc_5.0.2-3ubuntu6_all.deb ...
Unpacking zsh-doc (5.0.2-3ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Setting up zsh-doc (5.0.2-3ubuntu6) ...
scfc@toolsbeta-t68121-trusty:~$
```

This behaviour is consistent with the documentation in `apt_preferences(5)`:

> Several instances of the same version of a package may be available when the **sources.list**(5)` file contains references to more than one source.  In this case **apt-get** downloads the instance listed earliest in the **sources.list**(5) file.  The APT preferences do not affect the choice of instance, only the choice of version.

Is there any way to prefer the mirror over the original sources without changing `/etc/apt/sources.list`?  Can files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` ever be "earlier" than `/etc/apt/sources.list`?  Is there perhaps a configuration option that could be (ab)used for "mapping" the URLs?